# Can't figure out how to upload to arxiv from overleaf

Tags: overleaf, arxiv

I'm new to all of this. I exported my main.tex and my .eps files from overleaf and I'm trying to upload them to arxiv. I get the following error:

> Processing Status: Failed: File not found.

> Summary of Critical Errors:

> We detected an emergency stop during one of the TeX compilation runs. Please review the compilation log to determie whether there is a serious issue with your submission source.

> A file required by your submission was not found.
> ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `perctimespent-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found
> Please upload any missing files, or correct any file naming issues, and then reprocess your submission.

I know that I included this file. What am I doing wrong? And I assume that I don't know anything about packages or whatever. I simply took the package from the journal that I'll be submitting to: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/revtex-4-dot-2-template-and-sample/yydsrzvrqrzs

Any help would be great as I've never done this before.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I take it that you have a file called `perctimespent.eps`, which you uploaded to Overleaf, and that the main LaTeX file contains the statement `\includegraphics[...]{perctimespent.eps}`. Please change `\includegraphics[...]{perctimespent.eps}` to `\includegraphics[...]{perctimespent}` and see if it the tex file compiles correctly. If that's the case, just upload `perctimespent.pdf` and not `perctimespent-eps-converted-to.pdf'` to the arxiv server.

Comment: Hi there, Tom from Overleaf support here. As @Mico pointed out, it's not possible to use EPS figures when you plan to upload the project to arXiv. It's also listed in our arXiv submission checklist at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/LaTeX_checklist_for_arXiv_submissions Once you replace the EPS by a PDF (you can e.g. grab the converted image from the project's output files), the arXiv submission should work well.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked after converting to pdf.