# Arxiv Latex Upload Error (overleaf file)

Tags: overleaf, arxiv

I want to upload my paper in the Arxive. However, it gave me the following error.
I have one "Main.text" and "Main.bib" as the references and one "Figs" folder for the images.

Could you help me with that? Thank you so much

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do these links help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575594/cant-figure-out-how-to-upload-to-arxiv-from-overleaf#comment1449567_575594 and https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/LaTeX_checklist_for_arXiv_submissions#Are_you_using_any_.eps_image_files_alongside_.png.2C_.jpg_or_.pdf_image_files.3F

Comment: It seems you are using eps figures with nested folder structure. Neither is recommended if I was not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

In general, when it comes to specific issues with specific submissions, you should be contacting help@arxiv.org, or use our [contact help page](https://arxiv.org/help/contact) for a more immediate response. Also, when posting to this forum, helpers would need to have MWEs (Minimal Working Examples) when trying to diagnose this issue without having explicit knowledge of the guts of your submission, which is only possible as I work for arXiv.

The particular case you have here means that arXiv thinks you're missing a figure file at the location provided in your error screen shot. Of particular note is that you're running under `pdflatex`, which doesn't allow postscript figures in arXiv (arXiv doesn't perform any pre or post processing on figures required to use that file format). So, pdflatex fails because it's not in a format that's expected.

Your submission is ultimately failing because you are trying to use a mix of figure file formats, which is not allowed in arXiv's processing, as explained in the [FAQ](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/mistakes#mixed). You will need to unify the figure file formats under either pdflatex processing (typically recommended for file size reasons) or use latex (if you require postscript's fuctionality for things like `psfrag`).

Comment: You also need to adjust your `main.tex` file to align with our bibliography file naming requirements, or your `.bbl` file won't be read. This is explained on the [tex submission help page](https://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex#bibtex)